# How to pass JavaScript variable to Rails instance variables?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the javascript in the .js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         var i = 888
      $( "#previewpicture" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => "show_picture", :locals => { :@v_url => 'i'  }   ) ) %>" );
     });
```

@v_url is defined in the controller and  alert(<%= @v_url %>) is in the partial _show_picture.html.erb

The alert display i instead of 888. What is the correct syntax for    :locals => { :@v_url => 'i'}

Thanks 
Clin

Comment: I'm not sure, because I use Python rather than Ruby, but I think you're doing it wrong. What I mean is, not that you've got the wrong syntax or whatnot, but you're going about it in the wrong way. I don't think you're suppose to 'pass' client-side variables to server-side functions. You can POST them. Or GET them. But not 'pass' them.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, as JavaScript is a client-side language and Ruby is a server-side language. Ruby is parsed not only *before* JavaScript, but also on a completely separate machine with no way of interacting between the two.

Work out an alternative solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Ryan Bigg pointed, you cannot do this. But if you need a certain value to exist in both the server-side where your Rails is and client-side where your JS is, you would probably be better off storing that value in the server-side.

For example, you can have in your Rails controller:

```
@i = 888
```

And in your js template:

```
var i = #{@i};
```

Technically, this is passing a variable from Rails instance variable to JS variable. The reverse.

If you want to pass a JS variable from the client to the server, you can call an ajax request to the server passing in the variable as a parameter, and then let Rails respond with the template to be updated on your page.

Comment: global variable are fine. another way is to use jQuery native key-value storage **$.data**

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since JS is executed after the page is shown on your browser. However, if you need something on the page that depends on a Javascript condition or variable, you should make an AJAX call to your server, get the markup and place it in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I like the jQuery native **data** cross-browse key-value storage to save server-side variable depends on a certain object. JS variables are fine, but if you need to use object-oriented variables, just try that approach:

```
# erb file
<% javascript_tag do %>
  var i    = <%= server_variable %> // 888
  var obj  = $('#previewpicture');
  var data = $.data(obj, "vars", {v_url: i})
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "show_picture" %> #v_url will be assign by JS on page load


# js file
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#previewpicture').attr('v_url', data['v_url'])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to mingle the two with erb.  For example, with backbone.js:

```
#something.html.erb 
<script>
    function makeSomething() {
        Something.create({
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2,
            prop3: val3
          });
    }
</script>
```

Then in your controller:

```
def create
   ...some logic
  render :json => something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [client_variable gem](https://github.com/Coffa/client_variable), it wrap some functions for you to do it easier