# Passing javascript variable to partial via render_javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I receive a google ID from an Ajax call and then want to use that ID to update a button on my view.

Here is the code in new.js.erb, which is linked to a new.html.erb.

Problem is, I don't know how to pass the variable's content. Restaurant is  a json. The alert returns the correct ID and when I search my db on the terminal with the returned google id I find the restaurant.

Here is the code:

```
alert(restaurant["google_id"]);
    var google_id = restaurant["google_id"];
    $("#rating_bar").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'reviews/buttons/full_profile_rate_restaurant', :google_id => "+google_id+".html_safe) %>");
```

What happens is that the variable being passed is the string "google_id" instead of the combination of letters and numbers that is the google ID. I've tried multiple approaches, this is just one of many wrong one - I think this question is pretty easy for anyone who knows their JS really well.

Comment: Is your alert giving you the correct response? Is *restaurant* a hash? An object? - Please explain how *restaurant* is being populated with data.

Comment: Is the JSON data decoded into an object already? Or is it still a string containing JSON data? If its still a string, first make sure you parse it: var parsed=jQuery.parseJSON(restaurant);

Comment: Commander, all I need from the object is that one variable: the google ID, which is a string. I don't need the rest of the object. I do get the Google ID but the problem is how to pass it to my partial. Right now, every attempt I make passes the literal string google_id instead of the variable content, which is the string aw4t3q09wt4heoitp (for example)

Comment: Sorry, i missed your newer text in your latest edit. If the ID is correct at that point, then please try to pass it to #rating_bar alone and see if the displays result is correct. $('#rating_bar').html(google_id);

Comment: Yes Commander it passes. Looks like the problem is integrating the variable in a escapE_javascript call?

Comment: Is the code you want to pass to .html() somehow pre-parsed before it is sent to the browser? Can you pick up the rendered code and see if *google_id* is somehow integrated as a string at that point? Because generally what you pass to .html() looks fine. You can also try to put together the entire string first, store it in a variable, then pass this one to .html() - you could debug it in-between to see if its correct. You could also try to use single-quotes (make sure you escape the other single quotes by using \'), although i fail to see any logical reason why it would make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to pass a JS variable to the ruby partial.

As [Ryan Bigg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15245/ryan-bigg) explained for the same type of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951645/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-rails-instance-variables), its not possible to send the variable while rendering that partial. We need to work out some thing else. Even i also had the same issue once.

Alternatively,

if that is **google_id** is only a variable to display in the partial, then update those divs manually after rendering that partial.

like

```
$("#rating_bar").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'reviews/buttons/full_profile_rate_restaurant', :google_id => "sample_id") %>");
// Now update the required elements
$("#what-ever-ids").text(google_id);
```

or just create some other action in that controller, and call send an ajax request to that action, and there you will have this js variable, and in that **js.erb** file render the same partial which you actually want to update with the **google_id** variable.

Comment: Hey Saggar you are correct and I realied I make the same mistake over and over again. I have to find a way to re-render the partial after the model object has been created, basically, and I am racking my brains on how to do this.